# Animation in Unity is repeated 2 times

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I have an animation which plays when I activate trigger "shoot". When it activate, animation plays 2 times. If I change Transition duration, it either it is not played at all, or it is played twice.
Pls, help me. I work on Unity 2020.3.0f1. My english is not very well, sorry
UPD: OMG I find a path to fix it. You need to check is your animation running, and if it isnt - you can run it. Use GetCurrentClipInfo

Comment: Did you debug your line where you activate trigger "shoot", you might be calling that 2 times.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your animation is on loop. Check that.

Comment: No, it is not lopping